# Why does content disappear when I click on an empty area?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There is a .services section, which contains a .sidebar with a list-menu. When you click on one menu item from the menu in. The sidebar on the right in the .services-info block shows content that matches the content of the item, but there is a problem: when I click on an empty area, the content of the block in .services-info disappears. What is the problem?
**PS I am using Swiper JS for full page flipping of blocks and this is the first slide block**

Code jsfiddle.net/1ohrf34p/
Site cn76553.tmweb.ru

Selected item

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbjcB.jpg)

Clicked on any blank space

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBvA3.jpg)

```js
document.querySelector('ul.sidebar-menu').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let clickedId = e.target.parentNode.id;
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.services-info>div.content>div');
  divs.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.remove('visible');
    el.classList.add('invisible');
  });
  let targertEl = 'div.services-info>div.content>div.' + clickedId;
  document.querySelector(targertEl).classList.add('visible');
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide services-first-slider">
  <div class="services-bg">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h3>Наши услуги</h3>
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li id="business-card"><a href="#">Сайт-визитка</a></li>
            <li id="landing"><a href="#">Landing page</a></li>
            <li id="market"><a href="#">Интернет-магазин</a></li>
            <li id="corp"><a href="#">Корпоративный сайт</a></li>
            <li id="bitrix"><a href="#">1C Битрикс</a></li>
            <li id="advertising"><a href="#">Контекстная реклама</a></li>
            <li id="seo"><a href="#">SEO оптимизация</a></li>
            <li id="promotion"><a href="#">Продвижение в соц. сетях</a></li>
            <li id="marketing"><a href="#">Контент-маркетинг</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="services-info">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="business-card">Сайт-визитка</div>
            <div class="landing invisible">Landing page</div>
            <div class="market invisible">
              <div class="services-info-title">
                Созданные экспертами «Inter-web» сайты интернет-магазинов имеют функциональность, необходимую для успешной онлайн-торговли.
              </div>
              <p>Что входит в нашу работу:</p>
              <div class="services-info-block">
                <ul>
                  <li>+ Подготовка технического задания</li>
                  <li>+ Разработка прототипа</li>
                  <li>+ Верстка макета</li>
                  <li>+ Интеграция дизайна</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li>+ Написание уникальных текстов</li>
                  <li>+ Сбор семантики</li>
                  <li>+ Тестирование и запуск</li>
                  <li>+ Подключение веб-аналитики</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="services-info-footer">
                <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                <a href="#" class="details next">
                  <span>Узнать подробнее</span>
                  <div class="button-next"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="corp invisible">Корпоративный сайт</div>
            <div class="bitrix invisible">1C Битрикс</div>
            <div class="advertising invisible">Контекстная реклама</div>
            <div class="seo invisible">SEO оптимизация</div>
            <div class="promotion invisible">Продвижение в соц. сетях</div>
            <div class="marketing invisible">Контент-маркетинг</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you have code that adds the `invisible` class to all `divs` within `.services-info > .content`, which is pretty much everything except the sidebar. You may want to target the `li`s within `ul.sidebar-menu` rather than just the `ul`. You may also want to add CSS that sets `ul.sidebar li a { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }` so that there are fewer "empty spaces" to click on.

Comment: this is not a solution, because user can click anywhere and everything will be lost. I need to bind the event to the clicked element and so that the content corresponding to this element appears

Answer (score -1):

That is because you get an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div.services-info>div.content>div.' is not a valid selector.
You are trying to get the id of an element, which doesn't have it, and besides that, you are trying to reach it by wrong selector, using ".idOfElement" instead of "#idOfElement".

Comment: So what do I need to fix in the end?